# java runtime exception: unable to start activity componentInfo

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bluetooth, runtimeexception

I am building an app to communicate with rc boat using Bluetooth. But it is crashing on the device saying "unfortunately, Wheeler App has stopped.". So, i ran it in emulator, knowing that null pointer exception would be thrown at line 111 as it is not a real device, trying to find out what is throwing the runtime exception  saying "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" 
Here's my full code -

```
package com.in2gravity.wheeler;
package com.in2gravity.wheeler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
Handler mHandler;
private byte[] up, down, left, right, g1, g2, g3, g4, launch, dock;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Buttons Enlisting
    Button upnavbutton , downnavbutton, leftnavbutton, rightnavbutton,gearup1, gearup2, geardown1, geardown2, launchbutton, dockbutton;
    // texts Enlisting & id registration
    TextView propellerText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.propellerText);
    TextView in2gravityText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.in2gravityText);
    TextView timerText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    // imageview enlisting & id registration
    ImageView appLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.appLogo);
    //chronometer enlisting & id registration
    Chronometer timer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    //button id registration
    upnavbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upnavbutton);
    downnavbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.downnavbutton);
    leftnavbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.leftnavbutton);
    rightnavbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rightnavbutton);
    gearup1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gearbutton3);
    gearup2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gearbutton4);
    geardown2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gearbutton2);
    geardown1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gearbutton1);
    launchbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.launchbutton);
    dockbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dockbutton);
    // setting onclick listener to this class

    upnavbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    downnavbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    leftnavbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    rightnavbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    launchbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    dockbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    gearup1.setOnClickListener(this);
    gearup2.setOnClickListener(this);
    geardown2.setOnClickListener(this);
    geardown1.setOnClickListener(this);
    // converting strings to bytes for further use
    up = "u".getBytes();
    down = "d".getBytes();
    left = "l".getBytes();
    right = "r".getBytes();
    launch = "L".getBytes();
    dock = "D".getBytes();
    g1 = "1".getBytes();
    g2 = "2".getBytes();
    g3 = "3".getBytes();
    g4 = "4".getBytes();

    mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
            int end = (int)msg.arg2;
            switch(msg.what) {
            case 1:
            String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
            writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
            break;
            }
            }
            };

    Intent enableBluetooth = null;      
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter== null){
        String tag = null;
        // no bluetooth support!
        Log.e(tag, "Bluetooth is not supported in this device");
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        enableBluetooth = new   Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 1);
    }
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices =  mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
            mDevice = device;
        }
    }
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
    mConnectThread.start();

//  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//              .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
//  }

}
```

Connect Thread Class:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread{

            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
            private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");


            public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device){
                BluetoothSocket tmp =null;
                mmDevice= device;
                try {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                } catch (IOException e) {}
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    mmSocket =tmp;
                }
                public void run() {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    try {
                    mmSocket.connect();
                    } catch (IOException connectException) {
                    try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException closeException) {
                        return; 

                    }

                    } 
                    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
                    mConnectedThread.start();
                    }
                    public void cancel() {
                    try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) { }
            }
         }
```

Connected Thread Class:

```
    private  class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { 

        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }
        public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int begin = 0;
        int bytes = 0;
        while (true) {
        try {
        bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
        for(int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
        if(buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {
        mHandler.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
        begin = i + 1;
        if(i == bytes - 1) {
        bytes = 0;
        begin = 0;
            }
        }
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        break;
        }
        }
        }
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
        mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        public void cancel() {
        try {
        mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.launchbutton:

            //when launch button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(launch);

            break;
        case R.id.dockbutton :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(dock);

            break;
        case R.id.upnavbutton :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(up);

            break;
        case R.id.downnavbutton :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(down);

            break;
        case R.id.leftnavbutton :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(left);

            break;
        case R.id.rightnavbutton :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(right);

            break;
        case R.id.gearbutton1 :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(g1);

            break;
        case R.id.gearbutton2 :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(g2);

            break;
        case R.id.gearbutton3 :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(g4);

            break;
        case R.id.gearbutton4 :
            //when dock button pressed
            mConnectedThread.write(g3);

            break;
        }
        }

   }
```

Logcat:

> 04-10 06:27:33.389: D/dalvikvm(2489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51K, 5% free 
>   2977K/3124K, paused 64ms, total 68ms
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.629: D/dalvikvm(2489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 4% free   3425K/3568K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.729: E/BluetoothAdapter(2489): Bluetooth binder is null
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.729: E/(2489): Bluetooth is not supported in this device
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.729: D/AndroidRuntime(2489): Shutting down VM
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.729: W/dalvikvm(2489): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3cd2b20)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489): Process: com.in2gravity.wheeler, PID: 2489
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
>
> {com.in2gravity.wheeler/com.in2gravity.wheeler.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at com.in2gravity.wheeler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>
> 04-10 06:27:33.829: E/AndroidRuntime(2489):    ... 11 more

activity_main.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/appLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/wheelerapp_logo2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/upnavbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/appLogo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/upnavbutton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/downnavbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/upnavbutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appLogo"
    android:background="@drawable/upnavbutton"
    android:rotation="180" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rightnavbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appLogo"
    android:background="@drawable/rightnavbutton" />

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/downnavbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/leftnavbutton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Chronometer"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/propellerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/leftnavbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/launchbutton"
    android:text="@string/Propeller_Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/in2gravityText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/propellerText"
    android:text="@string/in2gravity_text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/launchbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rightnavbutton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rightnavbutton"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:text="@string/launchbutton_text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dockbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rightnavbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:text="@string/Dockbutton_text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/leftnavbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rightnavbutton"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/appLogo"
    android:background="@drawable/leftnavbutton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gearbutton3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/launchbutton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/launchbutton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/upnavbutton"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:text="@string/gearup2_text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gearbutton4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gearbutton3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/upnavbutton"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    android:text="@string/gearup1_text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gearbutton1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rightnavbutton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/downnavbutton"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:text="@string/geardown2_text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gearbutton2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gearbutton3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gearbutton1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:text="@string/geardown1_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/leftnavbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:text="@string/timer_text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

androidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.in2gravity.wheeler"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/wheelerapp_logo2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity
     android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:name="com.in2gravity.wheeler.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Note: I am using custom buttons in this app, if that helps. Among 10 buttons here is one (all of them are constructed in the same way)
upnavbutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_enabled="true" 
 android:state_pressed="true"      android:drawable="@drawable/upnavbutton_pressed" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/upnavbutton_normal" />

</selector>
```

Comment: what's at line 112 of MainActivity?

Comment: ` startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 1);` 
@Sonnet
this line would generally cause the exception as it is run on emulator, not in the real device, i know that, but apart from that, the savedInstanceInfo is always null, and the set content view never works, should it not? i mean isn't it supposed to show the view at least before crashing? if it is due to bluetooth then it should be only for bluetooth binder is null, i am aware of that, but why does it not show the activity_main.xml at least?

Comment: please post the logcat errors when running on real device..

Comment: @Sonnet sorry, my deviceis not showing on the active device list on the IDE, so i copied all the time the apk file onto my device and then install and run it. It's a drag :(

Comment: isn't there any way to help without having the logcat of the app running on real device?

Comment: since this is a bluetooth based project, you really should use a real device...  try switching the usb settings from "media storage" to "camera". this might help detect the device.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet did you mean view images option when the usb is connected? i activated the usb debugging mode on the device, and the feature you suggested too, but didn't work. (i manually set up the adb using google_usb from the sdk and i am using windows 8.1, if that helps)

Comment: You are cheking `if(mBluetoothAdapter== null)` and then (in both case) you use `mBluetoothAdapter` (in `mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()` ), this can cause a NullPointerException if `mBluetoothAdapter` is Null. Maybe this is not the reason of your `RuntimeException` but you must handle this case.

Comment: In your log, there is a message:  "04-10 06:27:33.729: E/(2489): Bluetooth is not supported in this device".

Comment: @Paulo thanks, but i generated that line to show if the device is not supported of Bluetooth, as in this case, it is the emulator and it does not have bluetooth functionality so the program logs that line to the logcat. It is not what you are implying i guess.

Comment: @Rami thank you. I would definitely see through that.

Comment: @RakibulHaq If you solved your own question, please add an answer with the solution and accept it so the question becomes answered.

Comment: @Luksprog thanks for the suggestion, i would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have studied a few cases causing this error and found that sometimes it is caused by the xml view we are setting the content view to. As in this program, at first I constructed the buttons and other views on `fragment_main.xml` file, then faced the null pointer exception at the button listeners. And I thought it may conflict with the program in any way.

So, I copy paste the whole xml into `activity_main.xml` then deleted the `fragment_main.xml`. And also commented out the layoutinflater for the fragment. This was causing problem like contamination in ids of views.

After that I ran the program and it works fine.